# Theming Views Display

Tags: 7, views, theming

Can I use Views templates to theme the row style output of a specific display in my view so it doesn't affect the other displays I created? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

1. on the view edit screen click on the display you want to theme
2. click on the "Advanced" tab so that it slides down
3. in the "Others" section click on the "Theme: Information" link
4. in the "Row style output:" section you'll see the template file names you can use, you are currently using the one that is bold, the last name is the most specific, i.e. something like views-view-fields--VIEWNAME--DISPLAYNAME.tpl.php

simply copy views-view-fields.tpl.php from the "theme" directory of the Views module to the directory of your theme, rename the file and modify as you wish (and clear the cache)